# Datediff in seconds overflow when under 68 years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.

If I run the following query:

```
select 
   max(DATEDIFF(SECOND, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0)) as EventDuration
from allEvent
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I know that using datediff with seconds can give this error when the 2 datetimes are more than 68 years apart.  This should not be my case since the oldest data in the table is january 2013.

I ran the following query to ensure that there is no Null DateTime

```
select count(*) 
from allEvent
where EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0 is null or EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0 is null
```

No record has null DateTime

If I add the following where clause to the query it works

```
select DATEDIFF(second, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0) as EventDuration
from allEvent
where DATEDIFF(Minute, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0) >= 1
```

This doesn't work:

```
select DATEDIFF(second, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0) as EventDuration
from allEvent
where DATEDIFF(Minute, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0) < 1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are there any instances where the start date is after the end date?

Comment: Take it in minutes and check the biggest and smallest value?

Comment: Or are the dates the same?

Comment: So the oldest is  january 2013.   select max(EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0), min(EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0),  max(EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0), min(EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0)

Comment: Just to make sure is your dates actual stored as DateTime types or are the stored as varchar?

Comment: As a bonus, SQL Server 2016 will introduce DATEDIFF_BIG(), which returns a bigint rather than int.

Comment: Note that your null check is checking start date twice.

Comment: @Paparazzi You got it, after looking at the data I found out that 2 records had an end date of '1900-01-01 01:00:15.000' but a start date in 2016.  Friday afternoon.....  You can post it as an answer and I will set it as accepted answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the oldest is january 2013?

```
select max(EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0), min(EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0) 
     , max(EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0)  , min(EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0)   
from table
```

Comment: It turns out that I had some EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0 that were '1900-01-01 01:00:15.000' with a EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0 in 2016.  So that's why I had the error.  I never thought of this scenario.  Your input help me find it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
select DATEDIFF(second, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0) as EventDuration
from allEvent
where ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, EventStartTimeStamp_UTC0, EventEndTimeStamp_UTC0)) < 1
```

Comment: Why do you suggest filtering on records where the two values are less than a minute apart?